# Debian: Set persistent winbind group for tape device

Tags: debian, winbind, dlt

A ProLiant server with Ultrium 6-SCSI tape driven by smartpqi, running Debian 10.13. Server is member of a Windows domain using winbind and nsswitch.conf:
`group: files winbind`. Group membership of `/dev/nst0` has been set to `backup` which is a group provided by winbind. `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-tape-persistent-names.rules` has been commented out to prevent Debian to create a local group `backup` at boot time (with winbind not yet available) shadowing the winbind group.

This has been working fine most of the time.

Today a user, member of `backup` has been working (successfully) with the tape, but upon `mt offl` all `/dev/nst*` and `/dev/st*` devices disappeared and were recreated a couple of seconds later in the (local) group `tape`. The log file shows (only):

```
Jun 21 09:07:29 backup kernel: [15871221.205788] smartpqi 0000:06:00.0: removed 0:0:6:0 0000000000000000 Sequential-Access HP       Ultrium 6-SCSI   AIO-
Jun 21 09:07:49 backup kernel: [15871240.755657] smartpqi 0000:06:00.0: added 0:0:-:- 0000000000000000 Sequential-Access HP       Ultrium 6-SCSI   AIO-
Jun 21 09:07:49 backup kernel: [15871240.755816] smartpqi can't handle SMP requests
Jun 21 09:07:49 backup kernel: [15871240.756752] scsi 0:0:7:0: Sequential-Access HP       Ultrium 6-SCSI   35GD PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jun 21 09:07:49 backup kernel: [15871240.762916] st 0:0:7:0: Attached scsi tape st0
Jun 21 09:07:49 backup kernel: [15871240.762921] st 0:0:7:0: st0: try direct i/o: yes (alignment 4 B)
Jun 21 09:07:49 backup kernel: [15871240.763414] st 0:0:7:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 1
```

This is consistent to the observed behavior, but does not provide any insights (to me). The problem could be reproduces three times and stopped reappearing afterwards. Now loading and unloading works just fine again. `winbind` had no connection issues at all during this time, the `backup` group was available via `getent(1)`.

What could have been the cause of this dis- and reconnects?

And, perhaps more important: Is there any way to pin the group membership of a device to a group which is dynamically provided via winbind? I managed to prevent changes, but as soon as the device is recreated, I still have a problem.